# Android Java - Access non-static variable outside class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm developing an android app where a data is send from one activity to another

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_project_details);

    final Intent data =this.getIntent();
    final String currentDocumentId = data.getStringExtra("clickedDocumentId");
    }

    public static String projectDocumentId(){
    return currentDocumentId;
    }
```

I don't know how to access the currentDocumentId variable outside onCreate(). How to do it?

> data is non-static

Comment: Make it a global variable and set it within `onCreate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a global variable at the top of your activity class, called `currentDocumentId`, note that it could be nullable.

```
private String currentDocumentId;
    
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_project_details);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    currentDocumentId = intent.getStringExtra("clickedDocumentId");
}

@Nullable
public String getCurrentDocumentId(){
    return currentDocumentId;
}
```